# Wordpress doesn't siplay latest of author's archive page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$posts_per_page = get_option('posts_per_page');

$category = get_the_category();

if ($category) {
    $category_id = $category[0]->term_id;
} else {
    $category_id = 0;
}

$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('post', 'fight'),
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'order'         => 'DESC',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
);

if ($category_id > 0) {
    $args['category__in'] = array($category_id);
}

$query = new WP_Query($args);
?>
```

And to diplsay paginations

```
        $big = 99999999999999999;

        $paginate =  paginate_links(array(
            'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'current' => max(1, $paged),
            'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
        ));

        wp_reset_postdata();
```

Problem is that this display me3 page. After I go to 3 page it display me that it doesn't have any posts. Fo you know why?